# Swap df1 column with df2 column, based on value

Tags: python, dataframe, lookup

Goal: swap out `df_hsa.stateabbr` with `df_state.state`, based on 'df_state.abbr`.

Is there such a function, where I mention source, destination, and based-on dataframe columns?

Do I need to order both DataFrames similarly?

`df_hsa`:

```py
   hsa stateabbr    county
0  259        AL    Butler
1  177        AL   Calhoun
2  177        AL  Cleburne
3  172        AL  Chambers
4  172        AL  Randolph
```

`df_state`:

```py
  abbr       state
0   AL     Alabama
1   AK      Alaska
2   AZ     Arizona
3   AR    Arkansas
4   CA  California
```

---

Desired Output:
`df_hsa` with `state` column instead of `stateabbr`.

```py
   hsa     state    county
0  259   Alabama    Butler
1  177   Alabama   Calhoun
2  177   Alabama  Cleburne
3  172   Alabama  Chambers
4  172   Alabama  Randolph
```

Comment: I think `vlookup` is better option for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply join after setting the index to be "stateabbr"

```
df_hsa.set_index("stateabbr").join(df_state.set_index("abbr"))
```

output:

```
    hsa county  state
AL  259 Butler  Alabama
AL  177 Calhoun Alabama
AL  177 Cleburne    Alabama
AL  172 Chambers    Alabama
AL  172 Randolph    Alabama
```

if you also want the original index your can add `.set_index(df_hsa.index)` at the end of the line

Comment: `df_hsa` doesn't have `state` yet. Do you mean `df_hsa.set_index("stateabbr")...`?

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 you right. I edited my answer. I also replicated your dataframes and now it works.